# Horizontally Scaled Kafka Consumers consuming different offsets

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I've been developing a kafka consumer application (C# in kubernetes) and have been running it as a single node for a while, consuming from a single topic.

I noticed today that the topic I have been consuming from was quite full - I was doing continuous processing and was at offsets  around ~38k (in general, agnostic of partition), but records my producer were putting on the topic (also, ignoring partition differences) were around offsets ~58k.

I decided to scale up another consumer pod - **same code and config all around (group id, etc)**

When it came online, it logged that it was processing messages in the ~58k offset range. I considered that this was maybe just a different partition, but I can see the same partition in both logs (with different offsets).

I was under the impression that if multiple consumers had the same groupid, that message consumption would be balanced between them, in order.

In other words, why wouldn't my second (or n-th) consumer come online and process messages in the same offset range as my first consumer which has been running for days?

I did eye some of the IConsumer settings such as:

- https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-dotnet/_site/api/Confluent.Kafka.ConsumerConfig.html#Confluent_Kafka_ConsumerConfig_QueuedMinMessages

which seems to specify the minimum number of messages to keep in a "local consumer queue" (Default: 100,000), but I don't know if this actually indicates that ConsumerA has laid claim on 100K+ messages and ConsumerB is naturally starting +100k down the line

Other notes:

- What limited access I have to the Administrative Tools (Control Center) shows that my consumer group id is about 900k messages behind.
- ControlCenter says my topic has 60 partitions
- Autocommit is not off (default: true)
- Regardless of the Autocommit setting I am still doing a _consumer.Commit(msg) at the finally{} block after processing each individual message
- I don't want to kill my long-running consumer (that's still processing like a champ) in the event that there's an offset retention problem and I will "miss" all messages in the delta between these two

Comment: So, you're not able to run `kafka-consumer-groups` CLI?

Comment: @OneCricketeer correct, unfortunately I don't have any CLI access. I could request the support team do it, but would rather only request that if it's sure to give answers.